# Strongswan(IKEv2) авторизация через LDAP

Tags: linux, vpn, ldap

Добрый день! 
Существует ли возможность прикрутить авторизацию через LDAP в Strongswan?
Пробовали связку freeradius+ldap+strongswan возникает ошибка: `received EAP_FAILURE, EAP authentication failed`
Получается ситуация аналогична [mail lists strongswan](https://lists.strongswan.org/pipermail/users/2016-December/010322.html)
Спасибо.

**upd**
Дополнительно вопрос ушел к разработчикам strongswan: https://wiki.strongswan.org/issues/2320#change-8472